# Cannot instantiate the type HttpTransportProperties

Tags: java, apache-axis

I am using Apache Axis2 to build a Soap request to a web service with Eclipse, specifically a web service from ServiceNow.

I've tried to used the "official" suggestion from the ServiceNow wiki to provide basic authentication in my request:

```
HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator basicAuthenticationTest = new HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator();
```

but I get an error: "HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator cannot be resolved to a type"

After this, I tried this:

```
HttpTransportProperties basicAuthentication = new HttpTransportProperties();
```

but also got an error: "Cannot instantiate the type HttpTransportProperties"

Any way to solve this?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am using axis2 1.7.4. Is it a problem of versioning? should i use an older one?